# Automatic Cookie expire in every 30 Minutes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, cookies, model-view-controller

I am using cookies instead of session in my asp.net MVC 5 application. I am encrypting the session values (Logged in User Id) and holding it in cookies and insert the value in one table as well. based on my client request to increase the security(In every request the cookie and database value will check to make sure the value is same)its working fine. Now the problem is application getting sign out automatically after 30 minutes, I have modified the session state cookie time out value to 240 minutes in IIS, by default its 30.
My Login code is

```
if (Login.CheckLoginCredential(user, pwd))
        {
            Guid uuid;
            uuid = Guid.NewGuid();
            Session["uuid"] = uuid;
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(uuid.ToString(), false);
            UserService usobject = new UserService();
            bool updatecookie = usobject.updatecookie(user, uuid.ToString());
            if (ispasswordExpired == false)
            {
                Login.makeuserInactive(user);
                TempData["expirymessage"] = "Your password expired. Please change your password.";
            }
            if (Login.checkloginStatus(user))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ResetPassword", "ResetPassword");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Message"] = "Incorrect username or password!";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
        }
```

IIS Session value changed here

[image: IIS Cookie value]

Comment: _my client request to increase the security_ - scrap this and use [Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Its a huge application. Some other developers implemented the system, I cant change the system like you suggested. Is there any other way to fix it.?